# How can I make Frame/Applet application in jar file?

Tags: java, html, applet, frame

I have a sample code `App.java`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class App extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {       
        getContentPane().add(new JLabel("App"));
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JApplet aplet = new App();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(aplet);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        aplet.init();
        aplet.start();
        frame.setResizable(false);              
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I compile it by means of `compile.bat`:

```
@echo off
cls
del *.jar
javac *.java
jar cfe App.jar App *.class
del *.class
```

When I double click on `App.jar`, I see a frame with text. That is what I wanted.

How can I also display this on a html page?

I try code below and it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>App</h1>
<applet codebase="classes" code="App.class" archive="App.jar
    width="300" height="300" " />
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The page shows `Error. Click for details.`
When I click, I see:

```
load: class App.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App.class
```

When I post `App.class` on html, everything works. I'm unable to post `App.jar`.
How can I do this so it works both as an applet and frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just deleted `codebase="classes"` from html and everything works :).